# Javascript: How to do linked list of functions or similar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an actions array. Basically these are a list of functions  that know the function to be fired next. I've tried lots of ways but can't get them to work reliably. I am doing gui and have pop up frames that callback when they have completed their work (Select file, edit properties etc.)

Example flow:

Task 1: open FileBrowser (iframe browsing control), when selected, execute Task 2
Task 2: get value from FileBrowser, open iframe FileProperties. when complete execute Task 3
Task 3: get FileProperties id, add id to in page control

Each task has to wait for a callback from the previous task. I am open to all ideas how to do this! The only thing is the step are generated server side so I need to avoid hard coding! Below is my attempt so far!

All ideas, gratefully received.

FruitBat

```
/* action array */
            var actions = new Array();
            var data = {};
            var op = function(fn, next, data) {
                this.op = this;
                this.fn = fn;
                this.next = next;
                this.data = data;
            };


        function one(myop) {
            var op1 = myop;
            var url = 'poptarget.aspx?cid=21&data=' + escape('[Id]=[2],[cid]=[3]');
            var frame = $().popFrame('UniqueId', { caption: 'Page Item', url: url, width: 'auto', modal: true });
            frame.bindEvent("cancelled saved", function(e, d) {
                console.log('other');
                callback();
            });
            frame.bindEvent("close", function(e, d) {
                console.log('close');
                op1.next.fn.call(op1.next);
            });
        };
        function two(myop) {
            console.log('woohoo');
        };

        actions.push(new op(one, two, null));
        actions.push(new op(two, null, null));
        var start = actions[0];
        start.fn.call(start);

        console.log(data);`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `.call()` incorrectly. See the [MDN doco on call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). As I understand it:

```
start.fn.call(start);  // sets 'this' to start
```

will call the function `fn` and set its `this` to reference `start`, which would've happened by default given that you call `fn` using dot notation from `start`. Within your function `one()` you are not using `this` at all, you are using a declared parameter that you seem to expect to be `start`. Try changing that line to this:

```
start.fn(start);   // passes start as a parameter
```

Also within your `one()` function you reference `callback()` which doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at any async/flow control libraries? For example, [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) provides a pretty comprehensive number of ways to chain functions together.